# Checkout a specific dev version of module using git

Tags: version-control

I want to checkout a specific dev version of the feeds module using git.  I have a site which is using feeds 7.x-2.x-dev.  On the modules admin page the module version number is reported as `7.x-2.0-alpha8+99-dev`.

I have cloned the feeds module repo but can't work out how to checkout that specific version.  I tried using `git checkout 7.x-2.0-alpha8+99-dev`, but it didn't work.  I guess if I knew the commit number I could check it out, but not sure how to easily work this out other than manually reviewing the commit log and working out what was the 99th commit after alpha8.  I am hoping there might be an easier way.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a git question than Drupal, but you can use `rev-list` command to retrieve a list of commit hashes since the `7.x-2.0-alpha8` tag. Using the tail command you can reverse the list to show the first 100 commits (I think the `+XX-` scheme is an offset from the first commit) then filter that down to the last result (which should be `+99-dev` commit).

```
git rev-list 7.x-2.0-alpha8^..HEAD  | tail -r -n 100 | tail -n -1
```